# Copy a link and launch it in a new window in Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, copy-paste, new-window

I have a link that I need to copy and Paste it in a new browser window. I have this following code snippet but it doesn't seem to work. I found this code snippet in StackOverFlow. I am getting blank window. Please advise. Thanks!

```
 shortUrl =  driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#url-text')

      shortUrl.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a') #highlight all in box
      time.sleep(5)
      newLink = shortUrl.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c') #copy
      time.sleep(5)
      actionChains.click(newLink).key_down(Keys.COMMAND+'w')
      newLink2 = shortUrl.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to copy a link and then launch it in new window,any specific reason? Instead of this,you can click link and open in another window.There is code for this action which is written in java:

```
  Actions act = new Actions(driver);
  WebElement onElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail"));
  act.contextClick(onElement).perform();
  act.sendKeys("w").perform();
```

Hope this code helps you!!!

Comment: It is not a clickable link. Basically short url displayed on a text box. I need to copy it and open in a different window to finish some more tests which depends on that url. Here is the element <input id="proposal-url-text" class="copy-url" type="text" value="" size="50" onfocus="this.select();" onmouseup="return false;">

Comment: You can achieve this through JS executor.Get inner text from element and try to open as                                                                            String url = elem.getText(); JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
     js.executeScript("window.open('" + url + "')");